# Adjust the element height in AngularJS

Tags: css, angularjs, html

I am working with AngularJS (pretty new). I have encountered a challenge which is if the textarea value is to big I have to make it scrollable as well as the border around it and if not I have to remove the border and scrolling as well. I try adding the directive but couldn't make it work.

Let me know if there is any work around it. I appreciate your time and help.

Updated:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('removeBorder', function () {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    if (element[0].clientHeight < element[0].scrollHeight) {
      console.log(element.clientHeight);
      console.log(element.scrollHeight);
      console.log('ELEMENT: ' + element[0]);
      angular.element(element[0]).removeClass('scroll');
    }
  }
};
});
```

Comment: please provide code whatever you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made you an example with nativeJS and angularJS with native JS. Just check Elements `clientHeight` and `scrollHeight`attribute to make it work.

### angularJS directive

```
angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', [])
.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {}])
.directive('removeBorder', function() {

  return { 
    restrict: 'A', 
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      if (element[0].clientHeight >= element[0].scrollHeight) { 
        console.log(element[0].clientHeight); 
        console.log(element[0].scrollHeight);  
        angular.element(element[0]).addClass('no-scroll'); 

      }
    }}; 
});
```

### Native JS - [Plunker](http://jsfiddle.net/nbzyju9L/2/)

```
function hasScrollbar(elemId) { 
    elem = document.getElementById(elemId); 
    if (elem.clientHeight < elem.scrollHeight) {
        alert("The element #" + elemId + " has a vertical scrollbar!"); 
    } else {
        alert("The element #" + elemId + " doesn't have a vertical scrollbar."); 
        elem.style.border= "0";
    }
}
```

Scrollable shoulb be set automatically. Or use css:

```
    textarea { overflow-y:scroll; }
```

Comment: Is there any way you can do this in directive(angular)?

Comment: Sure, implement it into a directive.

Comment: 'angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('removeBorder', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        if (element[0].clientHeight < element[0].scrollHeight) {
          console.log(element.clientHeight);
          console.log(element.scrollHeight);
          console.log('ELEMENT: ' + element[0]);
          angular.element(element[0]).removeClass('scroll');
        }
      }
    };
  });'

Comment: Thanks @lin. I am getting my clientHeight and scrollHeight to be 0.

Comment: Thank you! I figured out that I had some timing issue with angular. Thank you for your help! Cheers!